# react-split-pane cannot resize

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just installed [react-split-pane](https://github.com/tomkp/react-split-pane) in my application, but it does not seem to work.

I'm using react-split-pane version 0.1.68 but I tested it with 0.1.66 and 0.1.64 as well.

This is my component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SplitPane from 'react-split-pane';

class Edit extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <SplitPane split="vertical">
            <div style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}>LEFT</div>
            <div style={{backgroundColor: 'blue'}}>RIGHT</div>
        </SplitPane>
    );
  }
}

export default Edit;
```

I end up with a component that looks like I how styled it, but dragging between the elements to resize the width of the elements does not work.

[image]

What am I missing here?

Ps [this issue](https://github.com/tomkp/react-split-pane/issues/231) might be related to it, but I tried previous versions and they don't seem to work either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had a similar problem. The reason why divider doesn't work is: **missing CSS**

Add CSS from tutorial: https://github.com/tomkp/react-split-pane#example-styling
to your react component. For example:

```
import './edit.css';
```

Your dragging element will work.
[image]